# Center floated list

Tags: html, css

How can I make sure the floated list is always centered?

http://jsfiddle.net/sbfoeuns/

I tried:

```
.blocks {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

.blocks-inner {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}
```

But this does not help (resize the browser to see).

In contrast to this example where I took the code from: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxgoj

Comment: Don't use floats...use `inline-block`. Centering floated elements is **hard**. Floats aren't really suited to that.

Comment: Why dont you just use the code that you found in the codepen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will keep everything centered regardless of screen size and keep the boxes at a min-width.

Also, I removed the `margin` and `padding` from the unordered list which were slightly throwing off the midpoint.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gjh9e1gq/2/)

```
.blocks {
  width:100%;
}

.blocks-inner {
  width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.blocks ul {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.blocks li {
  display:inline-block;
}

.blocks li a {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  color: #818896;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  min-width: 140px;
  height: 85px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.blocks li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #d674c0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the below code. the thing is if you want to keep more than one elements in center of its parent. add `text-center` to parent css and `display:inline-block` to the number of childs

```css
.blocks {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.blocks-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.blocks li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}
.blocks li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  color: #818896;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  width: 140px;
  height: 85px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.blocks li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #d674c0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="blocks-inner">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">test</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">test</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">test</a>
      </li>

      <li><a href="">test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Both the css class

```
.blocks {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

.blocks-inner {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}
```

Add the Below one

```
.blocks-inner ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbfoeuns/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your HTML slightly, you don't need the extra nested `div.blocks-inner`.

First, apply `display: table` to `ul` to get a shrink-to-fit block level element to wrap your link elements.  You can then center the `ul` with `margin: 0 auto`.

Apply `display: inline-block` to `li`, which will keep these elements inline, and use `vertical-align: top` to fix the baseline-whitespace issue.  Note this gives you a nice way of controlling the spacing between the links using margin-right, and see the next rule with `:last-child` to tidy up the last `li` element.

Everything else with the `a` styling is fine.

Note that the link elements will wrap onto a second line for small screen widths, but that can be fixed, the details depending on your overall design goals.

```css
.blocks {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.blocks ul {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.blocks li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.blocks li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.blocks li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  color: #818896;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  width: 140px;
  height: 85px;
  text-align: center;
}
.blocks li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #d674c0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```